# Issues with whole-site caching on CDNs? (e.g. alternate content for mobile browsers)

Tags: mobile, cdn

We are considering hosting the core of our site (everything that doesn't need to be dynamically generated) on a CDN, so that our root domain (e.g. "http://example.com/") would point to the CDN, then everything dynamic would either point to an alternate second-level domain (e.g. "http://search.example.com/ for searches) or be layered on top of the static content by AJAX calls to an alternate domain (e.g. http://ajax.example.com/).

This seems like something that would be very desirable for lots of sites but I don't see much information even on the CDN home pages about doing whole-site caching.  There is at least one obvious problem that occurs to me, which is that we currently detect whether the user is coming from a mobile browser or not and serve mobile content if they are coming from a mobile browser.  The problem is that as far as I know, with most CDNs you can only store on version of a page, so if you cache the regular page, mobile browsers will see that instead of the mobile version (and obviously vice versa).

We could get around this to some degree by moving the mobile stuff to a separate domain like m.example.com but we would need the CDN to detect mobile browsers and redirect them to that domain (which we would also like to have hosted on the CDN, but pointing at the mobile content instead of the regular content, obviously).

It seems like this should be widely supported but I can't find much information on it. Has anyone done something similar?  If so, what CDN did you use and how did you address this issue?  Were there other significant hurdles that needed to be overcome?

Edited to add a couple of things I forgot:

We also considered redirecting to the mobile site using javascript but then obviously older phones without javascript would be left out in the cold and they are the ones that probably need the mobile version the most.

One constraint that may factor into any answers to this question is that we need the URLs of our primary site to be very specific for SEO purposes but we don't care at all about SEO for the mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

We have rules at our CDN (EdgeCast) that will cache multiple versions (Desktop, Iphone, Blackberry, etc.) of the same incoming Url. The CDN rules append a querystring to the request to the origin server.  Custom code at our origin server renders the proper version depending on the incoming querystring. For example:

```
Desktop:    CDN requests /?nomobile  origin server returns Desktop rendering
Iphone:     CDN requests /?iphone    origin server returns Iphone rendering
Blackberry: CDN requests /?mobile    origin server returns Mobile rendering
```

As far as the CDN is concerned, there are 3 different Urls, so 3 different pages are cached.  The querystring is completely transparent to the end user.  Even if you use a responsive design with media queries, this approach is incredibly valuable in giving you the flexibility to alter the HTML at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

If the rendering of your page is different for various devices (e.g. mobile phones) it is not a static content and should not be on your CDN.

Put only real static files on your CDN and consider a different caching strategy for your pages.

Anyhow instead of detecting the client's browser via JavaScript you could also do this on the server-side and actually I would recommend you that, instead of JavaScript. Then you could realize the redirect approach.

Hope that helps.